# How to extract the latest form responses of each emails with formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

### Input

| Timestamp | Email | Answer Field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/07/01 00:00:00 | a@sample.com | 1st of A |
| 2022/07/02 00:00:00 | b@sample.com | 1st of B |
| 2022/07/03 00:00:00 | c@sample.com | 1st of C |
| 2022/07/04 00:00:00 | a@sample.com | 2nd of A |
| 2022/07/05 00:00:00 | b@sample.com | 2nd of B |
| 2022/07/06 00:00:00 | a@sample.com | 3rd of A |

---

### Output

| Timestamp | Email | Answer Field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/07/03 00:00:00 | c@sample.com | 1st of C |
| 2022/07/05 00:00:00 | b@sample.com | 2nd of B |
| 2022/07/06 00:00:00 | a@sample.com | 3rd of A |

---

### Formula preferred (one or more):

`ArrayFormula`, `QUERY`, `FILTER`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following

```
=QUERY(A77:C85,"select max(A), B, max(C) where A is not null 
                group by B order by max(A)
                label max(A) 'Timestamp', max(C) 'Answer Field' ",1)
```

*(do adjust the formula according to your locale and ranges)*

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you? If yes, you could accept it and maybe [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well. If not we could try finding out why.

Comment: Thank you, I have forgot we could use `max` for it!